# prime factor of a number

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Here is the Question

```
f(x)=sum of power of prime factor of x
now if f(x) is given then find the least value of x which also setisfy the condition
(No of divisor of x)-1=f(x).
Eg: f(x)=2 given and i need to find x 
Step 1:check for x=2 then f(x)=1
Step 2:check for x=3 then f(x)=1
Step 3: check for x=4 then f(x)=2 (i.e-x=2^2,and we know that f(x) is some of power of prime factor so f(x) here is 2)
And divisor of 4 is 1,2 & 4 so ,no of divisor -1=f(x)

so the Answer is x=4.

Now the approach i followed
Step 1-start for i=2 till we get the answer
step 2-find the prime factor for i and calculate the sum of power
Step 3-check if calculated sum is equal to the f(x) or not if not then increment i and repeat from step -1.
```

Now my question is

1. I am starting from i=2 and checking for f(x) by increment i by 1 each time . is there any efficient way to do that?

   2. Also i am continuing the loop till i get the answer. can it be done with some other end condition because it might go in infinite loop? 
      Please help

Comment: if f(x)=y, isn' t the smallest solution always 2^y?

Comment: @Henry sry i missed the another condition there now added .thanks for lukng into it

Comment: The second condition does not change anything as 2^y has y+1 divisors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every number can be represented in the form of:

x = a<sub>1</sub><sup>p<sub>1</sub></sup>.a<sub>1</sub><sup>p<sub>1</sub></sup>...a<sub>n</sub><sup>p<sub>n</sub></sup>

Where:

a<sub>i</sub> 1 <= i <= n are prime factors.

So for the `x` to be minimum possible all factors should be `2`and so the `x` would be `2 ^ f(x)`.

Number of divisors of `x` is: (p<sub>1</sub> + 1)(p<sub>2</sub> + 1)...(p<sub>n</sub> + 1) so your added condition also will be satisfied!

Comment: i am really really sorry i missed a condition there (No of divisor of x)-1=f(x). now i added. thanks Man for lukng into it.

Comment: **`Happy Coding`** `:)`

Comment: I agree, but I can't understand how did you find that it's what op is asking about...

Comment: @xenteros, yes the question looks a bit cryptic at first! `:)`